# Ignore JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a test and I want that it should not be launched 
what is the good practice : set `Ignore` inside test? `@Deprecated`?

I would like to not launch it but with a message informing that I should make changes for future to launch it .

Answer (score 12):

I'd normally use `@Ignore("comment on why it is ignored")`. IMO the comment is very important for other developers to know why the test is disabled or for how long (maybe it's just temporarily).

EDIT:

By default there is only a info like `Tests run: ... Skipped: 1 ...` for ignored tests. How to print the value of `Ignore` annotation?

One solution is to make a custom [`RunListener`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html):

```
public class PrintIgnoreRunListener extends RunListener {
    @Override
    public void testIgnored(Description description) throws Exception {
        super.testIgnored(description);
        Ignore ignore = description.getAnnotation(Ignore.class);
        String ignoreMessage = String.format(
                "@Ignore test method '%s()': '%s'",
                description.getMethodName(), ignore.value());

        System.out.println(ignoreMessage);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, for normal JUnit tests, to use a custom `RunListener` requires to have a custom `Runner` that registers the `PrintIgnoreRunListener`:

```
public class MyJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyJUnit4Runner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        notifier.addListener(new PrintIgnoreRunListener());
        super.run(notifier);
    }

}
```

Last step is to annotate your test class:

```
@RunWith(MyJUnit4Runner.class)
public class MyTestClass {
    // ...
}
```

If you are using maven and surefire plugin, you don't need a customer `Runner`, because you can configure surefire to use custom listeners:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>com.acme.PrintIgnoreRunListener</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: so, I add @ignore("") before @Test, in this case test will not be launched but a comment will be shows, right ?

Comment: @lola: unfortunately the value is not printed out (don't know why - even if it should be an easy thing). There is only a `Skipped: X` counter in the summary.

Comment: @lola: I updated my answer on how to show the `@Ignore` annotation value

Answer (score 0):

If you use test suite, you can edit all test cases in one place. eg:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
WorkItemTOAssemblerTestOOC.class,
WorkItemTypeTOAssemblerTestOOC.class,
WorkRequestTOAssemblerTestOOC.class,
WorkRequestTypeTOAssemblerTestOOC.class,
WorkQueueTOAssemblerTestOOC.class
})
public class WorkFlowAssemblerTestSuite {

}
```